# Template does not rerender after state change due to async function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

Here I have a vue project with vite and firebase.
The function for the data call is in a separate firebase.js file with lots of functions.

I call 2 function in Orders.vue that do:
1: get all the orders based of current email adress
2: get all the products based on that order

These are the 2 function that are being called.

```
async function getOrders() {
  const dateNow = new Date();
  const year = dateNow.getFullYear();
  const ordersRef = collection(
    db,
    "Users/" + auth.currentUser.email + "/orders/" + year + "/orders"
  );
  const ordersSnapshot = await getDocs(ordersRef);
  let IDS = {
    orders: [],
  };
  ordersSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    IDS.orders.push(doc.data());
    // getDoc()
    // console.log(doc.data());
  });
  return IDS.orders;
}

async function getOrdersProducts(ids) {
  // was working on this function
  let products = [];
  await ids.forEach((idList, inx) => {
    console.log(idList);
    products.push({
      items: [],
      order: inx,
      date: idList.dateOrdered
    })
    // console.log(idList.productsId);
    idList.productsId.forEach(async (id, index) => {
      if (id.includes("monitor")) {
        const productsRef = collection(db, "Products/electronics/monitors");
        const q = query(productsRef, where('title', '==', id))

        const productSnap = await getDocs(q)
        
        productSnap.forEach((prod) => {
          products[inx].items.push(prod.data())
        })
      } else if (id.includes('speaker')) {
        const productsRef = collection(db, "Products/electronics/speakers");
        const q = query(productsRef, where('title', '==', id))
        
        const productSnap = await getDocs(q);
        
        productSnap.forEach((prod) => {
          console.log(prod.data());
          products[inx].items.push(prod.data);
        })
      }
    });
  });
  // console.log(products);
  return products;
}
```

I call these functions inside Orders.vue which looks like this

```
<!-- page to get all the orders from this person -->
<script setup>
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getOrders, getOrdersProducts } from '../../firebase'
import { onMounted, reactive, watch } from 'vue';
import { getStorage, getDownloadURL, ref } from 'firebase/storage';

const props = defineProps({
  user: String || null
})
const orders = reactive({
  list: []
})
const storage = getStorage()
const user = ref(false)

  getOrders().then((res) => {
      getOrdersProducts(res)
        .then( async (finalResult) => {
          console.log(finalResult);
          orders.list.push(finalResult)
        }).then(() => {
          // get the images and assign the correct image to the correct item
          console.log(orders.list[0]);

          for (let y = 0; y < orders.list.length; y++) {
            console.log(orders.list[0].items);
            for (let i = 0; i < orders.list[y].items.length; i++) {
              console.log('i = ' + i);
              getDownloadURL(ref(storage, 'products/' + orders.list[y].items[i].image))
                .then((url) => {
                    orders.list[y].items[i].image = url
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(url);
                  console.log(err);
                })
            }


          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })

// onMounted(() => {
//   if (props.user) {
//     asyncGetter()
//   }
// })

// asyncGetter()
</script>
<template>
  <div class="accountOrders">
    <h1>orders</h1>
    <!-- Was busy with rendering the order per user but did not have time for it yet -->
    <p v-if="orders.list">{{ orders.list }}</p>
    <div v-if="orders.list.length > 0" v-for="order in orders.list">
      <p>{{ order.date }}</p>
      <div v-if="order.items" v-for="product in order.items">
        <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

The problem is that my data does not render here:

```
  <div v-if="orders.list.length > 0" v-for="order in orders.list">
      <p>{{ order.date }}</p>
      <div v-if="order.items" v-for="product in order.items">
        <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to test if the second for loop was working and I found out that it doesn't because `orders.list[y].items.length` returns 0

```
   for (let i = 0; i < orders.list[y].items.length; i++) {
              console.log('i = ' + i);
              getDownloadURL(ref(storage, 'products/' + orders.list[y].items[i].image))
                .then((url) => {
                    orders.list[y].items[i].image = url
                    console.log(url);
                }).catch((err) => {
                    
                  console.log(err);
                })
            }
```

p.s. I still have trouble fully understanding .then and vue proxy

Comment: You should not use async/await within a `forEach()` loop, see the links in the duplicate. You can use `Promise.all()`.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Can you elaborate how to implement this in Orders.vue or Firebase.js?

Comment: Use the `forEach` loop to populate an Array with the promises returned by the Firebase asynchronous methods and then pass this Array to `Promise.all()`. I would kindly suggest to study the answer in the duplicate as well as the documentation for `Promise.all()` (link in the answer).

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I'm sorry but I am still stuck. Is there a way we can chat in private?

Comment: Yes we can. However I don't commit that I will be able to answer immediately as I'm busy